# How to correctly color a grayscale image through a UWP app?

Tags: c#, uwp, bitmapimage, grayscale, argb

I am working on an app and one of the main functions is it adjusts a gray scale image and apply a color to it.

this is the main math I am using to calculate this:

```
Color replaceWhite = Color.FromArgb(255, byte.Parse(acent.Substring(0, 2), 
    System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber), byte.Parse(acent.Substring(2, 2),
    System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber), byte.Parse(acent.Substring(4, 2),
    System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
WriteableBitmap source = await GetImageFile(sourceImage);
byte[] byteArray = null;
using (Stream stream = source.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
  {
    long streamLength = stream.Length;
    byteArray = new byte[streamLength];
    await stream.ReadAsync(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    if (streamLength > 0)
      {
        for (int i = 0; i < streamLength; i += 4)
          {
            if (byteArray[i + 3] != 0)
              {
                int b = Convert.ToInt32(byteArray[i]);
                int g = Convert.ToInt32(byteArray[i + 1]);
                int r = Convert.ToInt32(byteArray[i + 2]);

                int rB = ((((b * replaceBlack.B) / 255) + (((255 - b) * replaceWhite.B) / 255)) / 2);
                int rG = ((((g * replaceBlack.G) / 255) + (((255 - g) * replaceWhite.G) / 255)) / 2);
                int rR = ((((r * replaceBlack.R) / 255) + (((255 - r) * replaceWhite.R) / 255)) / 2);

                byte blue = Convert.ToByte(rB);
                byte green = Convert.ToByte(rG);
                byte red = Convert.ToByte(rR);

                byteArray[i] = blue; // Blue
                byteArray[i + 1] = green;  // Green
                byteArray[i + 2] = red; // Red
              }
          }
      }
  }
if (byteArray != null)
  {
    WriteableBitmap result = await PixelBufferToWritableBitmap(byteArray, source.PixelWidth, source.PixelHeight);
    StorageFile image = await WriteableBitmapToStorageFile(result, fileName, folderName);
    BitmapImage imageSource = await StorageFileToBitmapImage(image);
    return imageSource;
  }
```

The code luckily works however when an image is passing through it the colors appear much darker than the original. I know it is most likely a problem with the mathe but I cant pinpoint where it is.

[image: This is the image I am putting through the code. it is a png image]

[image: And this is the result. as you can see, the colors in the color picker are much different than the final result]

its worth mentioning I am using color stored in the app settings:

```
settings.Values["FlatWallpaperColor"] = theme.ColorCode;
string color = theme.ColorCode.Replace("#", "");
if (color.Length == 6)
  {
    SelectFlatWallpaperColorButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush (ColorHelper.FromArgb(255,
      byte.Parse(color.Substring(0, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber),
      byte.Parse(color.Substring(2, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber),
      byte.Parse(color.Substring(4, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)));
  }
```

Does anyone have experience in this and can help?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the calculation - you are taking a "mean" value of what already is a weighted average. You rather need to use the weighted average *itself* for each of the components of the color. So for example for `rb`:

```
int rb = (byte)((b/255.0)*replaceBlack.B + ((255-b)/255.0)*replaceWhite.B));
```

So we calculate how much intensive should be the `replaceBlack` color in by (dividing the amount of "white" in the original color by 255, and the same thing we do for `replaceWhite`. Then we can safely sum those two numbers, because it can never go above 255 (at worst you will be adding up `r * 255 + ( 1 - r ) * 255 = 255`) and if it does because some `double` rounding, the cast will still cut off the decimal part so we will have at most 255.

The original code was almost correct, but it basically used half the correct value - so everything got darker. Also using `double` values  for the calculation is better, as you will avoid potential rounding errors.